# Material UI - Theme is overriding the wrong component

Tags: material-ui, themes

I've made two Material-UI components.  Both are using themes.  However, the overrides on one theme are being used in the other!  I'm losing my mind trying to find a solution to this.  Here is the code:

This is being used for component1:

```
const themeForComponent1 = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
      root: {
        padding: '13px 0 0 13px !important'
      }
    },
  },
})
```

...and it is changing stuff in component 2, which happens to also have an element with the class "MuiInputLabel-root".

(edit: If it helps at all, the component is being called in Formik using the Field element via the "as" prop. Each component is using its own ThemeProvider element.)

Comment: Can you show the code? especiially where you define ThemeProvider?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two themes independent you can see the Material UI documentation here
https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/

But in the fact yo should use two theme providers. I say you that you should use an only theme and customize your component styles using Material UI functions to do that like CSS class

Comment: I'm not sure this is the idea you were thinking of, but each component already has its own <ThemeProvider> wrapper.  If it helps at all, the component is being called in Formik using the <Field> element via the "as" prop.